# Simple E-mail login with Python

Tags: python, forms, authentication, passwords

glad to be a part of the community! I'm trying to build a pretty simple login using Python, and I keep receiving the following error EOF when reading a line and a file error. Any idea on how I can resolve this issue? Thank you.

```
def password():
    p=raw_input("Password (6-15 Characters)")
    vp=raw_input("Verify Passord")
    if p.len() >= 6 and p.len() <= 15:
        if vp==p:
            email()
        else:
            print "Passwords don't match"
    elif p.len() <6 or p.len() >15:
        print "Password Invalid"
    else:
        print "Password Invalid"


def username():
    u=raw_input("Username (6-18 Characters)")
    if u.len() >=6 and u.len() <= 18:
        print "Valid Username"
        password()
    elif u.len() <6 or u.len() >18:
        print "Invalid UserName"
    else:
        print "Invalid UserName"

    username()
```

Comment: Try using the len function like `len(p)` instead of `p.len()`  Testing this code gives me "str object has no attribute len"  Not to mention that your elif statements are completely useless without a different error message specifying why that condition is invalid.

Comment: Aside from those, your code worked fine on my machine, barring the fact that email() was not explicitly defined.  Also, unindent the username() call.  This formatting will make the call recursive inside the definition.

Comment: Sorry, forgot to mention SyntaxError for empty input.  You might put your `raw_input` calls in a `try` block, then `except SyntaxError:` and set the variable to the empty string in that block, which will then be handled by your conditionals.